# How do I show a div with a form only if a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I have a table inside a div that contains a form for the user to fill out. Above the div is a button that says "Customer info". I want to show the form only if the customer wants to fill out the information. The idea is that if they want to fill it out they can click the button and the form will appear below. There are many of these sections so I only want the customer to have to see what they want to see. Below is an example...

```
<input type="button" value="Customer Info" onClick="">
<div>
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name:<input type="text" value="" id="name" name="name"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

My question is how can I write a simple javascript function that will act upon clicking the button that will show and hide the Div? The form would still be there just hidden and the values would just be blank.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is an entry level question that I need help with, consider who your helping when commenting. It would have been quicker to simply pass the question please notice all of the helpful answers that were posted. Also note that there was some debate amongst them which constitutes this question as worth while in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `onClick` event to do that:

## [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EaRuS/)

**HTML:**

```
<button id="some_id">Hide div</button>

<form id="some_form">

<form>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theButton = document.getElementById('some_id');
    
    theButton.onclick = function() { 
        document.getElementById('some_form').style.visibility='hidden';   
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, but seriously you're recommending in-line event handlers? And given the simplicity of the question, you may want to add the `script` tags too. And camel-casing the `onclick` is that necessary (any more)?

Comment: @DavidThomas Updated, just for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Inline javascript is considered bad practice

ie. `onClick=""`

Use something like this instead

```
<input id="info" type="button" value="Customer Info">
<div id="myDiv">
    <form>Name:
        <input type="text" value="" id="name" name="name">
        </input>
    </form>
</div>

var button = document.getElementById("info");
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

function show() {
    myDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hide() {
    myDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function toggle() {
    if (myDiv.style.visibility === "hidden") {
        show();
    } else {
        hide();
    }
}

hide();

button.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/3WMsq/)

Here is the code suggested by David Thomas in the comments. It performs exactly the same task, but uses shorthand if-else for the `toggle` function and doesn't provide you with separate `show` and `hide` functions.

```
<input id="info" type="button" value="Customer Info">
<div id="myDiv">
    <form>Name:
        <input type="text" value="" id="name" name="name">
        </input>
    </form>
</div>

var button = document.getElementById("info");
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

function toggle() {
    myDiv.style.visibility = myDiv.style.visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" :  "hidden";
}

toggle();

button.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/MecJx/)

Comment: Why not just the `toggle()` function, with a simple toggle? `myDiv.style.visibility = myDiv.style.visibility == 'visible' ? 'hidden': 'visible';`

Comment: No particular reason, except it is clear that the OP does not know how to perform any of this. Shorthand if-else is not clear for the inexperienced, and the user may change their mind about toggling, and they can easily play with all 3 functions. This example is just one possible solution of many.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#music").click(function () {
$("#musicinfo").show("slow");
});
</script>
```

you can change effect like as toggle, fadeToggle in place of show...