# How to show two forms using two buttons in html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, bootstrap-4

I'd like to create a page that allow users to create keys in a database. To do that, the user have first to choose between two buttons. Each button display a different form.

My problem is the next one : I can use **ONE** button that show **ONE** form. Here is the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16196022/12533349 :

**HTML**:

```
<button id="some_id">Hide div</button>

<form id="some_form">

<form>
```

**javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theButton = document.getElementById('some_id');

    theButton.onclick = function() { 
        document.getElementById('some_form').style.visibility='hidden';   
    }

</script>
```

But what I would like to do is the next thing :
*if the user click on **button_a**, it show **form_a**, if he clicks on **button_b**, but the **form_a** is displayed, the **form_a** is hidden and the **form_b** is displayed.* I hope it's more or less understandable...

Before concluding this post, I'd like to add a precisition : I use BootStrap 4 to construct my webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this for it.

```js
var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
var form2 = document.getElementById('form2');
// Hide the two forms when the page loads
form2.style.display = "none";
form1.style.display = "none";

// Create a function that shows and hides the forms
function showForm(x){
if(x==1){ /* Check what form should be shown */
form1.style.display = "block";
form2.style.display = "none";
}else if(x==2) {
form1.style.display = "none";
form2.style.display = "block";
}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showForm(1)">Form 1</button><button onclick="showForm(2)">Form 2</button>
<form id="form1">
<h3>Form 1</h3>
Example 1: <input placeholder="Example"/>
</form>
<form id="form2">
<h3>Form 2</h3>
Example 2: <input placeholder="Example"/>
</form>
```

In the code above, I used `style.display`, but you could also use `style.visibility`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers ! I'll try the code from @mjm0813 in a few time... By the way, how can I, by clicking on one button, add a value *A* or *B* to my database when the user clicks on the *submit* button ?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You stopped in the middle of the work, you had almost reached the goal. :)

However, returning to us, I think it's more elegant to use a class to add and remove in this way:

```
let theButton = document.getElementById('btn_id');
let theButton2 = document.getElementById('btn_id_2');
let element = document.getElementById('some_form');
let element2 = document.getElementById('some_form_2');

theButton.onclick = function() { 
   if(element.classList.contains('hidden')) {
   element.classList.remove('hidden');   
   element2.classList.add('hidden');   
   }
}

theButton2.onclick = function() { 
  if(element2.classList.contains('hidden')) {
     element2.classList.remove('hidden');   
     element.classList.add('hidden');   
  }
}
```

Remember to write your .hidden class with visibility: hidden